# glsl fragment shader color addition logic

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl, fragment-shader

I 'm trying to apply a filter to a texture in WebGL, but I can't get my head around how colors add up in my fragment shader.

Say I have this for example, adding red and black together like so:

```
vec3 red = vec3(1., 0., 0.);
color.rgb = vec3(0., 0., 0.) + red;    

gl_FragColor = color;
```

It outputs the color red as I would expect. On the red channel we have 0. + 1. = 1.

But when applying the same logic to my current texture color, for info the alpha channel = 1.

```
vec3 red = vec3(1., 0., 0.);
color.rgb = texture.rgb + red;    

gl_FragColor = color;
```

I get this before and after:

[image]

Blacks remain black and it colorizes the white area, what is going on? Why does it not follow the same logic?

How do I go about colorizing the image so that black becomes my desired color and everything else is a lighter varient of said color.

Here's the full fragment shader code:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_image;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_position;
uniform vec2 u_pointer;
uniform vec2 u_tex_size;
uniform float u_zoom;
uniform float u_mask_amplitude;
uniform float u_mask_top;
uniform float u_mask_bottom;

// the texCoords passed in from the this.vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

// scale from center
float scale(float a) {
    return a / (1. / u_zoom) - (.5 / (1. / u_zoom));
}

vec4 toGrayscale(in vec4 color){
    float average = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;
    return vec4(average, average, average, 1.0);
}

vec4 colorize(in vec4 grayscale, in vec4 color){
    return grayscale * color ;
}

float luminance(vec3 rgb){
    // Algorithm from Chapter 10 of Graphics Shaders.
    const vec3 W = vec3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
    return dot(rgb, W);
}

float dist(vec2 a, vec2 b){
    float x = a.x - b.x;
    x = x * u_resolution.x / u_resolution.y;
    float y = a.y - b.y;
    return sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
}

void main() {
    
    // Look up a color from the texture.
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
    
    float x = v_texCoord.x;
    float y = v_texCoord.y;
    
    
    // map position
    x = x + (u_position.x) / 3.;
    y = y + u_position.y;
    
    
    // repeat & scaling
    float repeat_x = mod((x * 3.0), 1.0);
    
    
    // texture
    color = texture2D(u_image, vec2(repeat_x, y));
    
    
    // mask_offset
    
    vec2 pointer = (u_pointer + u_resolution / 2.) / u_resolution - 1.;
    float tex_offset = u_tex_size.x / u_resolution.x;
    
    
    pointer = pointer / u_zoom;
    pointer.x = pointer.x + u_position.x * tex_offset;
    pointer.y = pointer.y + u_position.y;
    
    vec2 text_coor = vec2((x * 3.) - 1.5, y - .5);
    
    
    text_coor.x = text_coor.x * tex_offset;
    // text_coor.y = text_coor.y * tex_offset;
    
    
    
    
    
    
    // should invert
    
    float PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
    
    float mask_top = u_mask_top / u_resolution.y;
    float mask_bottom = u_mask_bottom / u_resolution.y;
    
    mask_top = mask_top - .5; // .5 is center
    mask_bottom = mask_bottom - .5; // .5 is center
    
    float width = 10000./u_resolution.x;
    float amplitude = u_mask_amplitude;
    
    bool top = scale(v_texCoord.y) + mask_top > sin(scale(v_texCoord.x) * width - (PI / 2.)) * amplitude;
    bool bottom = scale(v_texCoord.y) + mask_bottom < sin(scale(v_texCoord.x) * width - (PI / 2.)) * amplitude;
    bool invert = top && bottom;
    
    
    
    
    //
    
    float dist = dist(pointer, text_coor) * 1.5;
    if(!invert) dist = dist / 3.;
    
    color.r = color.r + dist * u_zoom;
    color.g = color.g + dist * u_zoom;
    color.b = color.b + dist * u_zoom;
    
    
    // greyscale
    
    float gray = dot(color.rgb, vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114));
    color = vec4(vec3(gray), 1.0);
    
    
    
    // invert
    
    if(invert){
        
        vec3 filter = vec3(0., 0.1215686275, 0.2039215686);
        color.rgb = 1. - color.rgb; // invert
        color.rgb = color.rgb + filter;
        
    }
    
    gl_FragColor = color;
    
}
```

Comment: Something else is happening not shown in the code you posted in your question. Add more code.

Comment: there is quite a bit going on, here's the full fragment shader code https://gist.github.com/saminton/b5e9d2ab650e161aa021bca9854227e4

Comment: It's mainly position manipulation, the only part that has anything to do with the color is near the end where I convert to greyscale and invert the texture color before trying to apply the filter

Comment: Oh and there's a masking effect, actually I think that might be where the problem is. If I have a color where color.r = .5 and I multiply the color by 4 does the color.r = 2. or will it stop at color.r = 1. I read that colors go from 0 to 1 so I presumed it would stop at 1.

Comment: It will stop at 1 on output unless you're writing to a floating point texture.

Comment: If you want us to look at your code you need to post it in the question itself. Just linking offsite is offtopic because once it disappears it would make the question irrelevant to anyone else.

Comment: well... so what is the alpha of the texture/color?

Comment: Ok, I'll do just that. I thought it would be a bit long to add all here.

Comment: I've found the problem, I guess i'm writing to a floating point texture like you said. though I have no idea what that means haha. Just before converting to greyscale I create a radius mask affect by multiplying the texture by a value. adding a min() function gives me the expected behaviour. I'll write a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help wouldn't have found it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what is going on. I have a radial mask effect where I am multiplying the texture by a value before applying the color filter like so:

```
color.r = color.r + dist * u_zoom, 1.;
color.g = color.g + dist * u_zoom, 1.;
color.b = color.b + dist * u_zoom, 1.;
```

Turns out by doing so the value of each channel can be greater or less than 1. So when I go to add the filter, even though the color appear black on screen It's value must be less, so adding .2 to -.5 for example remains black.